# Incongruency in the definition of homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology

$f$ and $g$ that map $X \rightarrow Y$ are homotopic iff there exists a homotopy $F(x,t) : X \times I \rightarrow Y$ such that $F(x,0) = f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$.

My question is:  Since $F(x,t)$, for any $x$ and $t$, will always be a map from $X \times I \rightarrow Y$ and $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ for any $x$, then shouldn't $F(x,0): X \times \{0\} \rightarrow Y$ and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ not be equal since they aren't the same function due to having different domains?

Comment: $F$ is a homotopy. $F(x,t)$ is merely an element of $Y$. $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$. $f(x)$ is merely an element of $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is that for every $x \in X$, $F(x, 0)$ (which is an element of $Y$) is the same as $f(x)$ (which is also an element of $Y$).

When you write that "$F(x, t)$, for any $x$ and $t$, will always be a map from $X \times I \to Y$", you are mistaken.

$F$ itself is a map from $X \times I$ to $Y$. $F(x, t)$ is the value of that function on a particular element of the domain, and hence is an element of the codomain.

I suspect that you've been used to referring to a function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ as "the function $f(x)$", which is a common abuse of language. The right way to refer to that thing (IMHO) is either "the function $x \mapsto f(x)$" (which clearly indicates that $x$ is a "dummy variable", to use the language of computer science for a moment) or as "the function $f$", which means just what it says. :)

If those distinctions don't make sense to you, it might be worth going back and reading really closely the definition of "function" in some decent mathematics text (i.e., not in your "high school algebra" text, which may be very good or may be horrible...)

Comment: So if $g : X \rightarrow E$, $p:E \rightarrow B$, and $F:X \times I \rightarrow B$ such that $F(x,0) = p \circ g(x)$ how would you draw a diagram relating them since $X \times \{0\} \neq X$?

Comment: You add another map, say, $i: X \to X \times I : x \mapsto (x,0)$. Then you can say that $p \circ g = F \circ i$ (which makes sense, because both are maps from $X$ to $B$). I'd draw this with $E$ in the upper right, $B$ below it, $X \times I$ to the left of $B$, and $X$ to the left of $X \times I$; you'll have two diagonal arrows from $X$ and $X \times I$ up to $E$.